# How to build a related content menu like this with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How can I build a left menu bloc like on this website ? > http://www.giantbomb.com/dark-souls/61-32697/
Let's say that this page is a content type named "Game", and the content is about a game named Dark Souls.

The left menu bloc is always the same for each content of the same type but the links are different (ex: http://www.giantbomb.com/quake/61-8015/). The links are about related content.

Details :

- links for Quake

Overview > website-url/quake/61-8015/

Guides > website-url/quake/61-8015/guides/

Characters > website-url/quake/61-8015/characters/

etc

- links for Dark Souls

Overview > website-url/dark-souls/61-32697/

Guides > website-url/dark-souls/61-32697/guides/

Characters > website-url/dark-souls/61-32697/characters/

etc

Is there a module or a magical Views query that can do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: This website is using those fields > http://api.giantbomb.com/documentation/#game . If it can help.

Comment: You have to define how content relates to each other first.  Is it by taxonomy terms?  By references?  If by taxonomy, then [Creating list of similar nodes in Drupal 7/Views 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3) might be helpful.

Comment: I prefer to do it with Relation module > http://drupal.org/project/relation
I will check your link, thanks.

Comment: Ok I checked with taxonomy and it's still confusing... how to do it with relation?