# Drupal 7 - show view without a specific node id

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I like to set a contextual filter with a NID that shouldn't show up in the result list when entered. However i can't find a way in drupal views. Is contextual filters the right approach?

Use-Case: Within a node, at the end of content there is a view loaded with more related topics to this node (they all share the same category). But, I don't like to see the current node within this view result.
How can I achieve this?

I am glad for every help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same problem years ago, and as far as I remember I've used [Relevant Content](http://drupal.org/project/relevant_content). But for Drupal 7 there is only a dev version, so here is a [comparison list](http://drupal.org/node/323329) of similar modules.

Also, check out this great answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367731/1003329 I guess it's exactly what you are looking for.