# Drupal related articles view with list of nodes to exclude from results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm trying to create a list of related articles in Drupal, based on shared tags.  I've used this solution and it works great:
[Creating list of similar nodes in Drupal 7/Views 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3/11367731#11367731)

However, I wish to expand on this and exclude certain nodes from the related view which are not relevant.  I have a node reference field (field_exclude) for the article which allows the user to select which nodes to exclude.

I just need to update this related view to exclude any node ids found in field_exclude.  Any idea on how I update the view to add this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **Filter Criteria** for the field_exclude and there set the "Not empty" value or any other value that wil do the job.

Comment: My answer assumes that you use the nid as argument to get the related nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here is to use the [NodeQueue](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module where users can add nodes in lists/views.